# Circular progress bar not covering whole available space

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, progress-bar

It's been a while I am stuck with this. #newbieAndroidDeveloper

I am working on a circular progress bar. The problem is the animating circle does not make use of the available space of the progress bar.

The screen shot should explain the issue.

[image]

The blue incomplete circle is the circular progress bar. Yellow square is the background of the progress bar. Red arrow is unused space which is the matter of concern.

Size of the progressbar and background is set via code.
I want to make the circular progress bar use the entire space.

**RaceLiveActivity.java**

```
public class RaceLiveActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Drawable drawable;
    String length;
    int len, totalDistance;
    TextView textViewDistance, textViewTime, textViewSpeed;
    FrameLayout raceFrame;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        totalDistance = 0;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_race_live);

        //TO FIND WIDTH AND  HEIGHT OF PHONE SCREEN
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

        //SET WIDTH AND HEIGHT 
        raceLiveActivity = this;

        ProgressBar prog=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams FrameLP1 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(displaymetrics.widthPixels-100 , displaymetrics.widthPixels -100 );
        FrameLP1.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        prog.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        prog.setLayoutParams(FrameLP1);


        length = "1";//int1.getStringExtra("length");
        len = Integer.valueOf(length);
        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt (progressBar, "progress", 0, 500); // see this max value coming back here, we animale towards that value
        animation.setDuration (len * 60000); //in milliseconds
        animation.setInterpolator (new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animation.start ();
    }
}
```

**activity_race_live.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/BackLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FD4C0D">
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/RaceProress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#FD4C0D"
        >
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
            android:progress="0"
            ></ProgressBar>

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**circular_progress_bar.xml** (drawable shape)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="0">
    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="3dp"
        android:useLevel="true">
        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="#005B7F"
            android:startColor="#005B7F"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false">
        </gradient>
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

Actually there are other elements in this activity. I have removed them to concentrate on the issue. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try adding to the progressbar: android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"

Comment: No. It  didn't help. No change in UI after adding that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I didn't find the answer why it is not using the unused space, I found another cool progress bar library which is cool. [ProgressWheel.](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel)

It's really customizable. You can adjust the size of the progress circle alone independent of the background which you can't do it with default progressbar tool of android. This solves my issue.

[image]

Hope it helps someone. But I am still curious why the default progress bar of android is not using up the entire space as mentioned in the question. Any helps are again welcomed.